# URL Rewrite Adjustment for Custom Post Type causes template to revert to index.php

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks, url-rewriting, template-hierarchy

I have a custom post type with a URL permalink rewrite that seems to work if it uses /mynews/stories/YYYY/mm/story-name but if I change "mm" to the first 3 letters of the month (eg Jan, Feb, Mar, etc), the template hierarchy breaks and it uses index.php.

My code is here http://pastebin.com/RS1DMbB6

I put this all in the functions.php file as I'm not allowed to add plugins.

So the moment I change from %monthnum% to %month%, the URL rewrite works, but the wrong template is being used. Debugging inside the post_type_link hook and template_include tells me is_single is null, and the template seems to go to index.php instead of single-story.php or even single.php.

Any ideas why this seemingly simple change breaks template hierarchy?

Comment: Please update your question. *Include* the minimal code we need to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Apologies. This is my very first post on StackExchange. The URLs I tried are /mynews/stories/2014/Mar/test1 where "test1" is the name of the post. This seems to make it use index.php instead of single.php. URL /mynews/stories/2014/03/test1 works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `%month%` isn't a recognized rewrite tag. If you [add the tag](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_tag) within your `init` action and flush permalinks, the query will succeed.

```
function register_story_post_type(){
    // your post type registration stuff here, and then…
    add_rewrite_tag( '%month%','([^&]+)' );
}
add_action('init','register_story_post_type');
```

There are also about a hundred ways you could otherwise clean up that code, but none relevant to your issue here. One thing I recommend though is to not manipulate rewrite globals directly, this is a bad habit that can get you in trouble if the underlying code changes. Always use the API and avoid globals. Your `story` rewrite tag is added when you register your post type, and the rewrite structure can be defined directly within your post type registration code using the `rewrite` argument.

Comment: Thanks Milo, I will update the globals. In it's current state the URL does rewrite correctly, but the template hierarchy is ignored and custom post type falls back to index.php for its template.